# Server through android application

Tags: android, database

I want to store a database in a server and access it through an android application. For example, every new user that use the application will be added to the database. Does anyone know how to do that? Do I need to build the server?

Thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to build a web server and have the database's services wrapped in calls to the web server. It would be similar to building a website that interacts with a web server on the back-end except that the android application is now making calls to the web server.

If you need help learning how to make asynchronous request to the server in android, you can start by looking at the AsyncTask class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: "Build a web server" is a bit confusing. Maybe name some technologies here

Comment: @user3212747 learning to build a web app on a web server that can communicate with an android application is no easy task. If you have a good amount of spare time, I recommend taking udacity.com's web development course. It is an extremely w ell taught course in web development. And it is completely free!! The only issue is the course is taught in Python and on GAE's framework. If you want to remain in java, you could take a look at the Play web framework and just try and read tutorials on it to learn how to use it.